# Doxygen plugin for qt-creator 3.3.0

Tags: plugins, qt-creator, doxygen

I want to install **Doxygen plug-in** from this [link](http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/wiki) on my **qt-creator3.3.0**. I do not find any packages for this version. I tried other versions and I didn't get any result.

Does anyone know what should I do?

I am using linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compile from source.

The weblink you provided has instructions on how to do that.